# How to fix "No module named 'azure.storage' " error in cloud azure function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure

Using a Python 3.6 enviroment in Anaconda, I'm able to run an azure function that accesses blob storage. Locally this function works fine, but when I post it on the cloud using VS Code and attempt a HTTP request, I get this error:

```
Result: Failure
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.storage'
Stack:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 230, in _handle__function_load_request
    func_request.metadata.entry_point)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/functions_worker/loader.py", line 66, in load_function
    mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/Convert/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
```

Why do I only get this error in the cloud enviroment and how do I fix it.

Comment: How did you set up the cloud environment?  Are you using a virtual environment?  Do you have a local file named `azure.py`?

Comment: I was not using a cloud environment, I was using VS code's Azure function extension. I did not have any local file named azure.py and when I did a full computer search I saw a few azure.py files in a local cache that I deleted before trying again but I am getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the solution I found was using the virtual environment and command line stuff like @Peter Pan was suggesting, but added azure.storage to my requirements.txt file. Once I did that it uploaded and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I recommanded you to follow the offical Quick start tutorial [`Create an HTTP triggered function in Azure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python) for Python to create a virtual environment for your function app and publish it within the virtual environment via command line, because all installed Python packages will be re-packaged and built to a publish file and deploy to your Azure Function App via `func azure functionapp publish <APP_NAME>` command. If not publish within the virtual environment, the deployment will be missing the required packages for your app.

And as @JohnGordon said in comment, please make sure your Azure Function App have been set up the correct environment for Python, not NodeJS or other language runtimes. If not, you can use the command `func azure functionapp publish <APP_NAME> --force` to force change its environment for runtime based on your virtual environment on local.

Also as @JohnGordon said in comment, if the two possible cases above are not real reason of your issue, you need to check your code files whether there is a file named `azure.py`, because the same file name `azure` will conflict with the package name of Azure SDK for Python.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So I went through and tried all of that. I made and deployed the function app via the command line using a test HTTP function that worked fine, but when I moved my code into the new function and deployed it via the command line I was getting the same errors. I am 100% sure the environment was set up for Python and I did a search of my entire computer to check for azure.py and deleted anything that showed up but I am still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the azure deployment issue by using below pip command:

```sh
pip install --target="$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r requirements.txt
```